# Geeksforgeeks compiler vs Hackerearth code table produces different output for the same code in c++ (gcc 5.4)

Tags: c++, gcc

this is my c ++ code for checking whether the sum of two primes is equal to the given input number 
though i have made my code for the question asked in geeksforgeeks
[here is the question](http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/primes-sum/0)

My solution code for the question is

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void ssprime(long int num,long int *primearray){
long int size=(num-2)/2;
bool primearr[size+1];
memset(primearr,false,sizeof(primearr));
for(long int i=1;i<=size;i++){
    for(long int j=i;(i+j+2*i*j)<=size;j++)
    primearr[(i+j+2*i*j)]=true;
}
primearray[0]=2;
int h=1;
for(long int i=1;i<=size;i++){
    if(primearr[i]==false){
    primearray[h++]=(2*i)+1;
    }
   }

}

  int main() {
      int test;
      cin>>test;
      while(test--){
       int num,size,f=0;
        cin>>num;
         size=(num-2)/2;
        long int parr[size];
      ssprime(num,parr);
    for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
       for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++){
           if(parr[i]+parr[j]==num){
             cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
              f=1;
       break;
         }
     }
   if(f==1)
       break;
     }
      if(f==0){
        cout<<"No";
            }
          }

         return 0;
     }
```

My question is my code is givin an output 

"Yes"
"Yes" in geeks for geeks while 
it is giving the correct output of 
"Yes"
"No" in hackerearth 

even though both of them are same compilers with the same version of c++(gcc 5.4)

i do not know why this is happening any one help me to sort this out..
is this the problem of geeks for geeks compiler or the version used in c++ in geeks for geeks is not the rght version ? 

 thanks in advance

Comment: Please fix the messy indentation of your code.

Comment: What input are you testing with?